# SSIS Execute SQL Task - Validating MDS model

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm developing an SSIS package that will pump data from a Data Source to an MDS data model\entity.

I have an execute SQL task which should validate the MDS Facility entity.

Here is the script:

```
DECLARE @ModelName nVarchar(50) = 'DEV ERP'
DECLARE @Model_id int
DECLARE @UserName nvarchar(50) = 'System'
DECLARE @User_ID int
DECLARE @Version_ID int
SET @User_ID =  (SELECT ID 
                 FROM mdm.tblUser u
                 WHERE u.UserName = @UserName)
SET @Model_ID = (SELECT Model_ID
                 FROM mdm.viw_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_VERSION
                 WHERE Model_Name = @ModelName)
SET @Version_ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)
                   FROM mdm.viw_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_VERSION
                   WHERE Model_ID = @Model_ID)
EXECUTE mdm.udpValidateModel @User_ID, @Model_ID, @Version_ID, 1
```

Here is the error I'm getting when trying to execute the task:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DECLARE @ModelName
>   nVarchar(50) = 'DEV ERP' DECLAR..." failed with the following error:
>   "SYSERR515|Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EnterUserID',
>   table 'MDS.mdm.tblEvent'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.,
>   @ErrorNumber = 515, @ErrorProcedure = "udpSystemEventSave", line 60".
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
>   property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or
>   connection not established correctly.

I was wondering how can I overcome this issue since I cannot declare the variable as a `NOT NULL` value. Before passing that variable how can I check the record is valid record or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @User_ID IS NULL
    BEGIN

        -- Handle it here.

    END
;
```